# Accessing large object (LONGBLOB) via a stream

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo

I am trying to use the database cache as a means to cache very large objects which I then want to stream instead of loading in memory and returning.

For this I have tried the following:

I created my database cache using the following migration:

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('cache', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('key')->unique();
        $table->longText('value');
        $table->integer('expiration');
    });
    DB::statement("ALTER TABLE `cache` MODIFY `value` LONGBLOB");
}
```

The reason for the alter is because `longText` does not work well with general binary objects which I needed to store.

I have then tried the following code to test streaming of the blob field:

```
public function test(Request $request) {
    cache()->store("database")
        ->put("randomStr", str_random(1024), 5); //Test string. Real cases are about 200 MB

    return response()->stream(function () {
        $fullKey = config("cache.prefix")."randomStr";
        $pdo = \DB::getPdo();
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("select `value` from `cache` where `key`=:key");
        $stmt->bindParam("key", $fullKey);
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $stmt->bindColumn(1, $lob, \PDO::PARAM_LOB);
            $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_BOUND);
            fpassthru($lob);
        }
    });
}
```

This code is based of the [PHP: Large Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php) manual page.

However I am getting the following error:

> fpassthru() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given

I've inspected the `$lob` parameter and seen that it's the actual string and not the stream to the LARGEBLOB field as I had hoped.

Is there any way to get the streaming of the BLOB to work in Laravel?

Note: Apparently there is [bug #40913](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40913) open since 2007 to fix this which now makes my question:

Is there any way to get a LARGEBLOB to be streamed to a response using `PDO` or `mysqli` or any other workaround in PHP?

Comment: Silly question .... but isn't this what *Jeremy Cook's* comment on the manpage about?

Comment: @CD001 possibly. I kind of automatically dismissed it seeing how the manual says it should work and the comment is a little bit old. I've now googled and it seems the bug is open for the past 11 years.

Comment: 11 years .... I think that qualifies it for being some kind of super-cockroach rather than a bug!

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I've figured out *a* way to solve this, but it is not pretty, not by a longshot.

So there's a few things happening here.

1. First of all I had to change my `cache()->driver(..)->put` approach to direct database manipulation. I did this because going through the database had a serialization step which I am not able to deal with when streaming the data out. In addition the endgame is to make the insertion a streaming operation as well so this will make it easier.
2. I installed the `mysql` command line client
3. I constructed a command line interface command that will get me the data I want, passing the correct authentication and constructing the query to pass via `-e`. Note: I could probably have done a better job escaping the shell arguments via `escapeshellarg` but for the life of me I couldn't get it to deal with backticks. Also note the `-N` parameter which is meant to remove the column headings from the result.
4. I used `proc_open` which allows the passing of the input/output streams back to PHP. I used this to stream the response out to the browser. Note: I've also defined other streams, I'm not a `proc_open` expert so I have no idea if this was necessary.

This is what the code becomes:

```
public function test(Request $request) {
    $fullKey = config("cache.prefix")."randomStr";
    \DB::table("cache")
        ->updateOrInsert([
            "key" => $fullKey,
        ], [
            "value" => str_random(1024),
            "expiration" => Carbon::now(new \DateTimeZone("UTC"))->getTimestamp() + 5*60
        ]);
    return response()->stream(function () use ($fullKey) {
        $command = "/usr/bin/mysql";
        $arguments = [
            "-h ".config("database.connections.mysql.host"),
            "-P ".config("database.connections.mysql.port"),
            "-u ".config("database.connections.mysql.username"),
            "-p".config("database.connections.mysql.password"),
            "-D ".config("database.connections.mysql.database"),
            "-e \"SELECT \\`value\\` FROM \\`cache\\` WHERE \\`key\\`='$fullKey'\"",
            "-N"
        ];
        $p = proc_open($command." ".implode(" ",$arguments),[
            [ "pipe", "r"  ],
            [ "pipe", "w"  ],
            [ "pipe", "w"  ]
        ], $pipes);
        fpassthru($pipes[1]);
        fclose($pipes[0]);
        fclose($pipes[1]);
        fclose($pipes[2]);
        proc_close($p);
    });

}
```

This seems to work, but it's not pretty. I will probably wrap it somewhere and never have to look at it ever again, but I am open for suggestions by anyone who can do better.

Note: All this just to work around a bug that's been opened for 11 years. I hope this actually helps someone else.

#### UPDATE

I have noticed that the bug is marked as resolved since Dec 2020. Checking this it does seem to actually work properly now. The bug was eventually resolved after almost 14 years.

This means the in the code from the question `$lob` is now a stream resource.