# Can PHPWord process source data from a string variable instead of a file?

Tags: php, phpword

I am pretty new to PHP and MySQL, and brand new to PHPWord. I have done multiple searches and cannot find the solution I am looking for.

I already have the PHP code to extract the plain text from an actual docx file located on the Windows file system.

My situation:
Some MS Word docx files are stored as blobs in the database using base64_encode(). I need to find a specified string in one or more of these files.
No rows are returned when I attempted to use FROM_BASE64('columnname') because the data is in the docx format, so the string does not match anything in the data.
Then I used a simple SELECT to get a docx file into a string variable.
I would like to avoid creating a temporary file to parse using PHPWord which would have to be done for each docx file.

My question(s):
Is there a way to use the string variable as the source for PHPWord processing? Or does PHPWord require the source to be an actual file on the file system?

Comment: Is there a problem with writing it to a temporary file ( creating one using https://stackoverflow.com/a/35465331/1213708)

Comment: I am currently creating and parsing them as temp files. Part of the problem is that some of the docx files are rather large. And as can be expected with actual files, creating and parsing each one from the database adds quite a bit of overhead, adding extra time to perform the search for a matching string. This is why I am hoping to find a way to process each file from the string variable.

Comment: Hmm, if you're using blobs, why do you store as base64? The first "b" in blob stands for _binary_, so these fields are binary safe. If you would store in a text column, you may wanted to have used that, but not for a blob column. See as well: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51539880/367456